# How to plot Implicit function Exp^(-ArcTan[y/x]) * Sqrt[x^2 + y^2]==C , for example, C -> Range[-12, 12]?

Tags: plotting, differential-equations, equation-solving

I tried many functions to plot implicit function:

```
Exp[-ArcTan[y/x]] *  Sqrt[x^2 + y^2]==C
```

Does anyone have an idea how to do that ? (This is General Integral of some Homogeneous differential Equations)

Answer (score 3):

Did you try [`ContourPlot`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ContourPlot)?

```
ContourPlot[
    Exp[-ArcTan[y/x]] Sqrt[x^2+y^2],
    {x, -5, 5},
    {y, -5, 5},
    Contours->Range[-12,12]
]
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

```
ContourPlot[Evaluate[Table[Exp[-ArcTan[y/x]]*Sqrt[x^2 + y^2] - c == 0, {c, 0, 12, 
1/2}]], {x, -5, 5}, {y, -5, 5}]
```

[image]

For range: `c=-12..0` plot not exist.

```
ContourPlot[Evaluate[Table[Exp[-ArcTan[y/x]]*Sqrt[x^2 + y^2] - c == 0, {c, -12, 0, 
1/2}]], {x, -5, 5}, {y, -5, 5}]
```